# Serve pdf using :remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a form_tag that generates a pdf and serves it to the user. The final send_data is like :

```
send_data pdf.render, type: 'application/pdf', :filename => filename, :compress => true
```

This works fine with a standar form, but it does not work when i try to use ajax to set :remote => true.

The ultimate thing i want to do is use :disable_with to disable the button while the pdf is generating.

Any ideas on how i could fix this ?

Comment: I do a lot of long running pdf generations (23 seconds in some cases),  and when finished the pdf is served to the user via send_data.  So my first question is why do you want to AJAXify the process?  If your pdf generations are VERY long running,  do you want to allow the user to continue to interact with the form WHILE the pdf is being generated?  If that is the case,  you'd have to have something on your form that says 'Your PDF is ready click here to download' when the PDF is ready.  Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: no, i just want to disable the generate button while generating and reenable when the procedure is over.

Answer (score 1):

I know is is an old thread but I thought I'd let you know how I got this to work in case anyone else finds there way here as I did.

The problem with using ajax for the request is that the response (the pdf file) is next to impossible to handle and then serve to the user as a file so don't bother. Instead I used rails built in caching to get the pdf served after generation.

1. Once you have the link working "conventionally" add the `:remote => true, :disable_with => 'loading...'` to your link to ajaxify it.
2. Set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in your config > enviroments > development.rb so you can see this working before pushing to production =p.
3. Use [Action Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) on your download action and set an appropriate expiration if required i.e. `caches_action :download, :expires_in => 5.minutes` at the top of your controller.

   This means that when you click on your link it will send the ajax request, generate the pdf and return the page. Now the page is cached so if you click the link again the request will take milliseconds not seconds. Next all we need to do is a little javascript to download the pdf once its ready.
4. However you do your javascript (unobtrusively or not) add the following:

```js
$("#download_link").on('ajax:success', function(){
    document.location = $(this).attr("href")
});
```

This will get the browser to follow the link as if the `:remote => true` wasn't there once the ajax request is successful (i.e. the pdf is generated). Because the response has been cached it'll download immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1. use a remote link to begin the rendering process
2. Have your server begin a background job to create the PDF, return to the user a job id
3. Use javascript to poll the server on a timer, sending the job id and asking if it's complete
4. Once it is complete, redirect the user to a page where they can download the PDF.

Comment: yes, that is something i have thought of as an alternative. But can it be done without the intermediate step of redirecting to the download page ? Like immediately download ?

Comment: You can just disable_with on a normal button -- if you disable the button and the server responds 20 seconds later, you might be golden.

Comment: yes, but the problem is that since remote true is set, it responds with js and i do not get the send_back data to the browser, though the button is working correctly.

Comment: Right, but I said to only add "disable_with", not setting it to remote=>true. It should still respond with HTML

Comment: if you respond with HTML, then you cannot know when the process was completed and the button will automatically reenable itself without being able to do background processing on my side.

Comment: Right, you mentioned you didn't want background processing, so I gave you a solution without background processing. Which is: `disable_with` that disables the button, and the server will respond when it's finished.

Comment: again, it's a different solution, because it needs an intermediate step. It's simple, but it's not what i am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

OK,  you have to use the various AJAX callbacks.

Assume you have a link on your page to generate the PDF.

```
<%= link_to 'Generate PDF', '/generate_pdf', :id=>'genpdf', :remote=>true %>
```

Now you have to bind events to the 'genpdf'  element created by the above.  i.e.

```
$('#genpdf').bind('ajax:beforesend', disablepdf)
$('#genpdf').bind('ajax:complete', enablepdf)
```

Then define the two javascript functions declared above to manipulate the HTML element as needed.

```
  var disablepdf = function() { $("#genpdf").removeAttr("disabled") };
  var enablepdf = function() { $("#genpdf").attr("disabled", "disabled") };
```